# Duplicate components by button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create components by clicking a button. It works. But generated components are up to down. I want them to be left to right.

```js
import { Card, Button } from "antd";
import "./Card.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

const CreateCard = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
    const addTodo = (event) => {
        setTodo(todo.concat(<Todo key={todo.length} />));
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Card hoverable className="card" title="New Project" style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }}>
                <Button onClick={addTodo}>CREATE</Button>
            </Card>
            {todo}
        </div>
    )
}
export default CreateCard;
```

This is the code where a card with the button.

```js
import { Card } from "antd";
import "./Card.css";
const Todo = () => {
    return (
        <Card hoverable className="card" title="New Project" style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }}>
            <p>Merhaba</p>
        </Card>
    )
}
export default Todo;
```

This is the Todo component. When I wrote  tag instead of card component, it worked as I want. But I want to generate a card left to right. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use flex row

```
import { Card, Button } from "antd";
import "./Card.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

const CreateCard = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
    const addTodo = (event) => {
        setTodo(todo.concat(<Todo key={todo.length} />));
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Card hoverable className="card" title="New Project" style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }}>
                <Button onClick={addTodo}>CREATE</Button>
            </Card>

            <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>{todo}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default CreateCard;
```

Comment: It's better to use old state like `setTodo(oldTodo => oldTodo.concat(<Todo key={oldTodo.length} />))` rather than `setTodo(todo.concat(<Todo key={todo.length} />))`

Comment: Agree, there are a lot of room for improvements. The question was how to place items vertically with CSS though.

Comment: I thought it would be better to do such kind of improvements as they are hard to debug and may give unintended results. So, just mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But components are being generated side by side as infinite. How can i add some of them into next rows?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the react components in the state, we can maintain the count and based on the count we can loop through and generate as many `Todo` components.

And for aligning them side-by-side one of the ways is by using `display: flex`.

```js
const  { Card, Button } = antd;
const { useState } = React;

const Todo = () => {
    return (
        <Card hoverable className="card" title="New Project" style={{ width: 150, height: 100 }}>
            <p>Merhaba</p>
        </Card>
    )
}


const CreateCard = () => {
    const [noOfTodos, setNoOfTodos] = useState(0);
    const addTodo = (event) => {
        setNoOfTodos(oldTodo => oldTodo + 1);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Card hoverable className="card" title="New Project" style={{ width: 300, height: 100 }}>
                <Button onClick={addTodo}>CREATE</Button>
            </Card>
            <div className="todos-container">
               {Array.from(Array(noOfTodos).keys()).map(todo => <Todo key={todo}/>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<CreateCard />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.todos-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.13.1/antd.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

> Note: For simplicity I have modified the height of the card from `200` to `100` and width from `300` to `150`.

Comment: It is going to right endless. How can i arrange rows in these code?

Comment: how can i arrange rows and cols here? Because in the solution that you've gave me,components are going left to right endless.

Comment: You can add `flex-wrap` to the container. I have updated the answer with the same.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use *display:grid* for it

```
<div style={{display: "grid", grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr))}}>
     {todo}
</div>
```

Comment: But components are being generated side by side as infinite. How can i add some of them into next rows?

Comment: Have you try my solution ? I think it will move some of them into next rows if it doesn't fit in one row.